# AWS API gateway to Lamba integration for custom java class object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda with a lambda handler which takes a custom java class object and returns another custom java class object. I want to connect it to a frontend portal so that I can send a query and receive a corresponding response back.

I know I have to use API Gateway for connecting the frontend to my lambda, but how to map that request from frontend to the custom java class object which my lambda takes and similarly how to map that response from the lamdba which is another custom java class object to the required response by the api?

Is it to do something with the models and mappings in api gateway which I am not able to understand for custom object inputs and outputs from the lamdba handler? Or I have to change my lambda handler altogether so it takes json input, output?

I am trying to do this through cloudformation templates not through console. I am a complete newbie in AWS and Web development in general so please any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by 'receives a custom java object'. Can you add the code of your lambda? At least enough to know what data you are receiving. You might need an non-proxy integration that translates the request to the json the lamda receives. You can check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html

Comment: Why you need lambda to create custom object ,Api gateway you can do that when return response.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html